# Install ubuntu in dualboot with windows 7

Tags: dual-boot

I can't install ubuntu using an external dvd writer/reader, when I'm selecting "install ubuntu inside windows" the screen goes black and dvd is ejected from dvd tray, then if I press anything my pc is rebooting.

I see something like:

```
acpid: exiting 
speech-dispatcher disabled; edit /etc/default/speech-dispatcher 
*Asking all remaining processes to terminate... [ OK ]
```

then the dvd is ejected from the bay.

What's wrong?

Comment: please edit your question with the given new information

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, wubi doesn't work properly for recent versions, so you need to set up a proper dual boot. This can be done by burning Ubuntu to a cd (download the .iso to do this), then choosing to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7. There is a possibility this doesn't work, in which case you will need to use `boot-repair`.

Comment: Sadly, I can't boot from my external dvd writer, I put it on the first thing to read in bios but, my bios is ignoring it.

Comment: Are you sure this is the only CD drive in your BIOS? Try having all media boot before your hard disk, and see if that helps.

Comment: I did that, first I put usb dvd reader; usb external HDD; hdd; normal dvd and that's all.

Comment: Did you burn the disc in the proper mode? Your system may only boot to UEFI or Legacy disks.

Comment: Yes, on my other pc is booting fine.